# Change value for paginate_by on the fly

Tags: django, pagination

I would like to be able to allow users change the default page size (paginate_by). My current page size is set to 10; I'd like to have buttons for say 25, 50, and all.

I am running Django 2.2 and Python 3.73 with postgresql 11.4.  My views.py creates a queryset and sets up pagination.  My prod_list.html template properly displays the data in pages with ten rows per page.

Here is what I currently have in my views.py:

```
class ProdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Proddetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProdSerializer


class ProdListView(ListView):
    model = Proddetails
    template_name = 'prod_list.html'
    # added for pagination
    context_object_name =  'prods' #Default: object_list
    paginate_by = 10
```

I want to be able to let my users change the number of rows per page.  I'm thinking I need to reset ***paginate_by*** based on which button the user clicks, but how can I do that?

Thanks--

Al

Well, I tried to comment, but that didn't give me enough room.  I hope this is the correct way to do this:

Thank you very much; that did the trick. I modified it to give me buttons with the page numbers, though, and I'm getting an odd behavior. I have a for loop that I use to put out the page numbers as buttons:

```
{% for i in DataPaginated.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if DataPaginated.number == i %}
    <button class="w3-button w3-amber">{{ i }} </button>
  {% else %}
    <a href="?page={{ i }}" class="w3-button">{{ i }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the pagination is set to the default of ten this works properly and shows three pages (there are 24 items).  If I change the pagination to 20, it looks right at first and shows two pages.  However, if I click on the second page, it changes my pagination back to 10, shows three pages again, and places me on the 2nd of the three pages.  Is there something I can do to keep my pagination locked at the setting chosen with the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
    
class ProdListView(ListView):
    model = Proddetails
    template_name = 'prod_list.html'
    # added for pagination
    context_object_name =  'prods' #Default: object_list
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get(self, request):

        paginate_by = request.GET.get('paginate_by', 10) or 10
        data = self.model.objects.all()

        paginator = Paginator(data, paginate_by)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            paginated = paginator.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            paginated = paginator.get_page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'DataPaginated':paginated, 'paginate_by':paginate_by})
```

you should put this in your template to allow to the user to select the pagination. you may send the number of paginate by  the form using the method GET. the view may get it.

once the view get the data (paginate number) passed by method GET it process the request then it give you a response that include the paginate data you should render in the template.

```
<form method="GET">
    <select name="paginate_by" id="">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">10</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Paginate">
</form>

<!-- RENDER YOU LIST HERE. Now context_object_name must be DataPaginated or whatever name you call it-->

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if DataPaginated.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1&param={{param}}">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ DataPaginated.previous_page_number }}&param={{param}}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ DataPaginated.number }} of {{ DataPaginated.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if DataPaginated.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ DataPaginated.next_page_number }}&param={{param}}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ DataPaginated.paginator.num_pages }}&param={{param}}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

[Django Documentation Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/)

**.get_page**

The .get_page method was added in Django 2.0. On older versions you will need

```
 try:
     paginated = paginator.page(page)
 except PageNotAnInteger:
     paginated = paginator.page(1)
 except EmptyPage:
     paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

You can check what version you are using when you do `manage.py runserver`. In my case it is `version 1.11.17`.

```
(ECOMME~1) C:\Users\HP\EcommerceProject>python manage.py runserver

Django version 1.11.17, using settings 'EcommerceProject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped a lot.  I had a follow up question, and I added that to my original post as there wasn't enough room in a comment.  --Al

Comment: if it helped to solve you problem you should mark as solved you are welcome

Comment: Sorry, meant to do that.  It is done now.  Did you happen to see my additional question that I added in my initial question, or should I make that a new question?  The items per page doesn't stay set, when you go to a new page with the pagination controls.  Thanks!

Comment: it is normal. if you change of page the items will do it too.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to override the get method, the correct way to do this is overriding the method `get_paginate_by`:

```py
  class VideoView(ListView):
    template_name = "pages/videos.html"
    model = models.Video
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        return self.request.GET.get("paginate_by", self.paginate_by)
```

Now you can filter: `http://localhost:8000/videos/?paginate_by=40`

Greetings.

Comment: This is the correct way, thank you. Overriding get_context_data with get method was a grind :/