# Keeping items per page static while paginating

Tags: django, pagination

I posed a question and got a quick response (thanks, Bob!) on how to do pagination in Django:

[Change value for paginate_by on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487336/change-value-for-paginate-by-on-the-fly/57487509?noredirect=1#comment101477376_57487509)

However, as outlined below, I'm having an issue getting the items per page to remain set.

I modified my ProdListView.html template to show buttons with page numbers, but, while it works, I'm getting an odd behavior. I have a for loop that I use to put out the page numbers as buttons:

```
{% for i in DataPaginated.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if DataPaginated.number == i %}
    <button class="w3-button w3-amber">{{ i }} </button>
  {% else %}
    <a href="?page={{ i }}" class="w3-button">{{ i }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the pagination is set to the default of ten this works properly and shows three pages (there are 24 items). If I change the pagination to 20, it looks correct at first and shows two pages. However, if I click on the second page, it changes my pagination back to 10, shows three pages again, and places me on the 2nd of the three pages.

In the interest of space, you can find the code I'm using in the views.py file and template file, besides the fragment above, in Bob White's answer here:

[Change value for paginate_by on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487336/change-value-for-paginate-by-on-the-fly/57487509?noredirect=1#comment101477376_57487509)

I would like whichever items per page is picked in the form to stay set while the user pages through the output until/unless they choose to change the items per page again.   Is there something I can do to keep my pagination (items per page) locked at the setting chosen with the form?

Thanks--

Al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in the views, you have a line: `paginate_by = request.GET.get('paginate_by', 10) or 10`, but I don't see in your template that you're sending `paginate_by` query param?

This will basically reset your pagination to `10` if you don't explicitly provide it.

Comment: Well, duh.  I was spending too much time looking at the css and ignored the param.  I've corrected all the links to:  '<a href="?page={{ i }}&paginate_by={{paginate_by}}" class="w3-button">{{ i }}</a>'. Now it works.  Thanks!.