# modify the value of paginate_by for all pages

Tags: python, django

I have a follow-up question on the answer to [Change value for paginate_by on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487336)

I added the following in the HTML

```
<form method="GET">
   <select name="paginate_by" id="">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Paginate">
</form>
```

and this function in my `ListView` class

```
class ReviewPostListView(ListView):
    model = Reviews
    template_name = 'reviews/reviews.html'
    context_object_name = 'rows'
    ordering = ['id']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        return self.request.GET.get("paginate_by", self.paginate_by)
```

it is working great, and the `paginate_by` is added to the URL. My problem is when I click on the second page it goes back to 5.

This is my pagination HTML

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {%if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

What is the pythonic of keeping the paginate_by (if exists) parameter in the URL when looping on the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `{{ request.GET.paginate_by }}`, you can access the `paginate_by` query parameters in your template.

So, your pagination HTML will look like:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
  {% firstof request.GET.paginate_by "5" as paginate_by %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1&paginate_by={{ paginate_by }}">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {%if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}&paginate_by={{ paginate_by }}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}&paginate_by={{ paginate_by }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

`firstof` is will set the value of `paginate_by` to the query parameter or `5`, which will be the default value.

Comment: I had to add `self.paginate_by = self.request.GET.get("paginate_by")` in my `get_queryset`, but this was exactly what I was looking for !
thanks

Comment: You should use `get_paginate_by` method for `self.paginate_by = self.request.GET.get("paginate_by")`. It is the standard method for getting pagination size.

Comment: I tried that `def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):` `return self.request.GET.get("paginate_by")` it didn't work

Comment: @goku If this answer helped you, please accept it so that others can see that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I did

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your HTML template:

```
<select name="paginate_by" onchange="location = this.value;">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="?paginate_by=5&{{page_obj.number}}">5</option>
      <option value="?paginate_by=10&{{page_obj.number}}">10</option>
      <option value="?paginate_by=20&{{page_obj.number}}">20</option>
      <option value="?paginate_by=50&{{page_obj.number}}">50</option>
</select>
```

Pass the `paginate_by` object into the html and add it to the pagination links. see below code:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {%if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what do I change in the pagination HTML?

Comment: it doesn't work, when I go to next page I get all the objects. the url becomes "http://127.0.0.1:8000/review/2/?paginate_by=&page=2"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template tag which will handle the query params for you.

Here are two simple tags

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def add_get_param(context, **kwargs):
    "Used to add/replace query parameters to the current URL."
    params = context["request"].GET.dict()
    params.update(kwargs)
    return "?{}".format(urlencode(params))


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def remove_get_param(context, *args):
    "Used to remove query parameters from the current URL."
    params = context["request"].GET.dict()
    for key in args:
        params.pop(key, None)
    return "?{}".format(urlencode(params))
```

And your HTML will look like

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={% add_get_param page=1 %}">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% add_get_param page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{% add_get_param page=num %}">{{num}}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?paginate_by={{ paginate_by}}&page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {%if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% add_get_param page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% add_get_param page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

With this whatever was already there in the query params will continue to be there, only the page will be changed. So this works if you decide to add more params such as for filtering.